# How does companies do Anti-DDoS Protection

Tags: networking, server, port, router, ddos

I want to ask about "How people do Anti DDoS and filter Traffic"

So I know most Hosting German companies have Anti DDoS Protection And Filters on traffic

I don't know if they code something to filter traffic on ports

Also in my think, people do like "Iptables on Gateway Server" so all traffic has been filtered before it has gone to the server

I need to know how to start on this way

Thanks

Comment: Search for RTBH`.You must kill it upstream from your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have an own network/rack/asn in order to filter traffic with XDP and hardware firewalls. Iptables are not helping very much on udp / they only deny traffic.